# Cell Reference not working for a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a formula =DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!'2045033_0' works fine. But i want the code which in this case is 2045033 to be a cell value, that i can change as per my need.

So, I want a formula like =DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!'& A1 &"_0'". But this does not work. Any help on this?

Also tried "DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!'" & A1 & "_0'" but did not work as well

PS: Adding underscore is mandatory.

Comment: Please post the code you're using

Comment: `DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!'2045033_0'` looks like a function call where `2045033_0` is a parameter. Single and double quotation marks and their precise location would be of the essence. I would try `DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!"'" & A1 & "_0'"` or perhaps `TEXT(A1)` or, to the contrary, `INT(A1)`. What is `DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!`? Is that a worksheet?

Comment: No, its not a worksheet, its a function to retrieve RTD data from a server. Ill try your method as well

Comment: I tried this ="DARTSCRDE|StrikePrice!" & "'" & A1 & "_0'"
But this returns the string, if there is any way we could pass this string to formula again, i think we would done!

Comment: @InsightAcademyPrivateTutori - Have a look at the `=INDIRECT("A1")` formula.

Comment: @Enigmativity same thing, it is returning the string, but not the evaluation result

Comment: @InsightAcademyPrivateTutori - I've added a answer that shows you how to use `INDIRECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `INDIRECT` worksheet function.

Try this:

1. In `A1` enter `A2`
2. In `A2` enter `5`
3. In `B1` enter `=INDIRECT(A1)`

`B1` should have the value of `5` now.

[image: INDIRECT]

You just need to make sure that the string inside `INDIRECT` is valid in your case.